# Como passar um array como parâmetros ou argumentos?

Tags: php, array, funções, parâmetros, argumento

Eu tenho duas funções:

```
function example($param1, $param2)
{
    echo $param1 . $param2;
}

function frutas($fruta1, $fruta2, $fruta3)
{
    echo $fruta1 . $fruta2 . $fruta3;
}
```

E também tenho uma variável que recebe os parâmetros das funções em forma de um *array*:

`$array = ['param1', 'param2'] // para função example()`
ou
`$array = ['fruta1', 'fruta2', 'fruta3'] // para função fruta()`

Eu posso passar os valores manualmente desta maneira:

```
example($array[0], $array[1])
```

Eu não quero passar manualmente porque a função `frutas` por exemplo, tem 3 parâmetros e não 2. E eu gostaria que fosse automático, passando todos os argumentos. Como se fosse um `foreach`.

Existe uma maneira de eu fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem muito controle sobre isto, muita coisa pode dar errado. Tem que saber o que está fazendo.

## PHP 5.6

```
example(...$array);
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). Isso costuma ser chamado de *splat*.

## PHP anterior ao 5.6

```
call_user_func_array("example", $array);
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/Params.php).

Recomendo evitar isso tanto quanto possível. Se vai criar a função, então faça ela aceitar o *array* também, ou faça outra que aceite um *array*. É bem melhor. Faça só quando não tem outro jeito. Mesmo assim, para poucos argumentos (e é raro não ser assim) eu sempre faria na mão.

Comment: Pq é bom evitar? No meu caso n tem como eu fazer manualmente...

Comment: Primeiro porque é gambi. Segundo porque não é necessário. Terceiro porque não é fácil fazer certo, mas se for, era fácil fazer manualmente. Porque não tem? Acho isto impossível.

Comment: O que eu estou tentando fazer é o seguinte: Usar funções fora do servidor, em outro. Ai no caso eu preciso passar os parâmetros para utilizar a função e ele vai em forma de array então não tem como eu fazer manualmente, já que cada função é diferente.

Comment: Isto não faz sentido.

Comment: pq? Desculpa sou meio inexperiente...

Comment: Se não faz sentido, você tem que explicar. Aí quem sabe possa fazer. Voc}o botou um exemplo manual na pergunta.

Comment: Posso falar com você pelo chat?

Comment: Agora entendi o que você quis dizer, Realmente a minha pergunta não tem nada haver com isso que disse no comentário, é pq no caso eu fiz a pergunta pra que não sirva apenas pra mim, resolva minha dúvida e também ajude os outros. Se eu for explicar tudo na pergunta ela ficaria muito grande e não iria direto ao assunto. Apenas comentei o que eu estava tentando fazer com a resposta desta pergunta